# Simple RegeX going wrong

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect two pages.

1. /blog.php to /blog/

and

2. blog/?p=1 to /blog/

I have this where only 1 is working now.

```
RewriteRule ^blog\/$ blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog\/$ blog\/?p=1 [L]
```

Can't figure out how to combine these two.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Just guessing: `RewriteRule ^(.*)blog(?:\/|\.php)$ $1blog/? [L]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog/? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ blog/ [NC,R=301,L]
```